# Managing docker containers with ansible - best practices

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm considering using both docker and ansible. The idea I had was to use ansible to set up my instances and I was wondering what would be the best practice to do so:

1. Calling ansible from the dockerfile on every container (which would necessitate having ansible installed on every container/instance. This method is mentioned in the [ansible up and running book](http://www.ansible.com/ansible-book), on the docker episode); or
2. Running my containers and then setting up all the instances by executing ansible-playbook.

What would be the best approach? Are there any other alternative ways for such use case?

Comment: What do you mean by 'setting up instances'?

Comment: using ansible to configure/set up the containers. If I need to install anything or deploy anything on the container or run any task that ansible can run. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use Ansible to setup your docker hosts (i.e. instances), you don't need to install Ansible on the remote machine. You install Ansible on your primary machine, and run playbooks and ad-hoc commands from there. This is why Ansible is a good tool for this kind of task (i.e. installing things on remote machines).

For example, if your remote docker host is a CentOS 7 machine, you could use the following playbook to install docker based on the [Docker install directions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/)

```
- name: Install Docker on remote hosts
  hosts: docker-hosts
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install docker
      shell: curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

Note that the `docker-hosts` group is defined by your hosts/inventory file.

Once you have docker installed on the remote machines, you can create another Ansible playbook to create/run your containers.

We commonly use the Ansible `shell` module in lieu of the `docker` module. This is more for convenience and reference. So later on, someone can look at the shell command you use to deploy containers remotely as an example for their own development (i.e. "How do you run that 'docker run' command again?")

Comment: Yeah, that's what we ended up doing, so I'm going to go with this answer for now. Btw- how do you set up the images then? Is it part of your ansible tasks (using docker_image) or is it being done before hand, by the CI system (as the book suggests)?

Comment: We have nightly builds on our CI system (Jenkins) that creates and pushes the images. We have other scripts which tag all of our images for various stages of deployment, dev, qa.

Comment: We don't use the `docker_image` module. We messed around with it, but moved away from it in our Ansible scripts. Oh, and we're using plain old shell scripts in the CI builds, no Ansible there.

Comment: Thanks again- this makes a lot of sense to me :)

Comment: "`You install Ansible on your primary machine`": If you have already installed Docker on your primary (which should be the case), then you can use an ansible Docker image (I prefer this one: [williamyeh/ansible:alpine3-onbuild](https://hub.docker.com/r/williamyeh/ansible/))